# MySQL: Check if I want to insert an already existing value using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table with a column that I want to insert data into but not existing data.

To give an example I have a day column and a customer. The same customer cannot have the same date twice, so I have a customer named Karl and he is on monday. If I try to add Karl to monday, when he is already existing on monday, it should not do that. How do I do this? Assuming I am using JTextFields to type the name and day.

So far I got this to insert data which works (though without checking if it's already existing!)

```
s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM customer");
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer values ('"+name.getText()+"', '"+day.getText()+"')");
```

How do I check if what I type in name textField and day textField both exist in same row?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can create a `unique constraint` which covers both of the `name` and `day` columns. Then, on every attempt to insert a duplicate pair, the database will throw an error, which you can handle on the Java layer.

Comment: Do you mean that I should assign the "unique" option for both columns or is that unique constraint you are talking about something else? And thanks alot for this swift answer :)

Comment: do select query and execute insert query on base of result of select query.

Comment: Something like 
if(rs.getString(1) == Karl && rs.getString(2) == monday)

error else insert?

Comment: On Which perpective do you accept a convenable answer, back or front control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name=? AND date=?");
s.setString(1, name.getText());
s.setString(2, day.getText());
ResultSet result = s.executeQuery ();
if(result.next()) {
    // dupilcate records present. don't add
} else {
    // add records to table.
    s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer values ('"+name.getText()+"', '"+day.getText()+"')");
}
```

Comment: It didn't work and went directly to the else loop but when I tried with the first column only it worked for that column. But then the problem will ofc. be that I can't put the same customer for different days. I don't know whether I missed something

Comment: You know what, I am completely ignorant regarding this. I found my mistake and was almost certain that I was the one making a mistake :P Thanks alot! I will mark this as my solution as it solved my problem.

Comment: This is injection vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

From the database perspective, @Kocko has already suggested that you can create a unique constraint.
Now, if you want to check as you type in your textbox then you can cache the data from the table and then check as you type or finish typing, but you need to consider points like who all can insert etc.
You can also use Ajax for help which silently goes to server without loading whole page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I can try this too perhaps :)